# How to sort column names based on values in a column of another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, dplyr

I have two dataframes as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame (a  = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  b = c(6,7,8,9,10),
                  x = c(6,7,8,9,10),
                  d = c(6,7,8,9,10),
                  z = c(6,7,8,9,10)
                  )
df1
```

looks as :

```
a   b   x   d   z
1   6   6   6   6
2   7   7   7   7
3   8   8   8   8
4   9   9   9   9
5   10  10  10  10
```

another dataframe df2

```
df2 = data.frame (km = c("d","z","b","x","a"))
```

looks as follows:

```
km
d
z
b
x
a
```

I want to order the columns of first dataframe as per row values of second dataframe such that output is as follows:

```
d   z   b   x   a
6   6   6   6   1
7   7   7   7   2
8   8   8   8   3
9   9   9   9   4
10  10  10  10  5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, simply subset the columns of `df1` using `df2$km`:

```
df1[, df2$km]
```

Or with dplyr, use `select(all_of())`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  select(all_of(df2$km))
```

Result from either approach:

```
   d  z  b  x a
1  6  6  6  6 1
2  7  7  7  7 2
3  8  8  8  8 3
4  9  9  9  9 4
5 10 10 10 10 5
```